# LINQ UpdateCheck on parent "LastUpdatedOn" field while updating children

Tags: linq

Is it possible to set "UpdateCheck" to "LastUpdatedOn" field of parent object while updating children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very confused by this question. The ColumnAttribute UpdateCheck can only be set to one of the following : Never, WhenChanged, Always.

If you are trying to timestamp a parent object when a property in a child object is changed, you can use partial methods to capture the change event and run other statements there.

```
public partial class MyObject
{
    partial void OnMyPropertyChanging(string value)
    {
        // fire set other linq against parent here  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! You just hit the nail on the head.